# How to insert a key value pair in an empty yaml file in ruamel.yaml in Python?

Tags: python, yaml, hiera, ruamel.yaml

My objective is to insert a key value pair in a YAML file which might be empty.

For example, my `hiera.yaml` (used in puppet) file contains only three hyphens.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ruamel.yaml
import sys

def read_file(f):
  with open(f, 'r') as yaml:
    return ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml)

dict = {}

dict['first_name'] = sys.argv[1]
dict['last_name'] = sys.argv[2]
dict['role'] = sys.argv[3]

data = read_file('hiera.yaml')

pos = len(data)
data.insert(pos, sys.argv[1], dict, None)


ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, open('hiera.yaml', 'w'), block_seq_indent=1)
```

I am running it like:

./alice.py Alice Doe Developer

I get an output like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./alice.py", line 16, in <module>
    pos = len(data)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

But when my hiera.yaml file is not empty, for example:

```
$ cat hiera.yaml
john:
$./alice.py Alice Doe Developer
$ cat hiera.yaml
john:
alice:
  first_name: Alice
  last_name: Doe
  role: Developer
```

Then it works properly.

Please tell me how to insert a key value pair(in my case a dict) to an empty YAML file. The examples of ruamel.yaml official page use doc string as a sample YAML content and then insert key-value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty scalar in a YAML document gives you the `null` YAML object that loads into Python as `None`:

```
a: 1
b:
```

The value for key `b` in data loaded from this will be `None`.

An empty file, or an empty string, from which your data is loaded using ruamel.yaml is considered the same as a file/string that contains the scalar `null`:

```
null
```

If you load that, you get `None` back, and you cannot add new keys to that.

To be sure check if the data you loaded is a `dict` or a subclass of a dict (in case you load with round_trip_load, you will get a ruamel.yaml.comment.CommentedMap), or check if it is None:

```
 data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(open('myfile.yaml'))
 if data is None:
     data = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
 data.insert(len(data), key, value)
```

You have to use a `CommentedMap()` as a normal Python dict doesn't have a method `.insert()`

Beware thought that a toplevel item in YAML file might also be a scalar (string, integer, datetime, etc) or a sequence (which gets loaded as a list). The former probably cannot be `.inserted()` upon, and the later (list) takes only a single parameter for `.insert()`

Answer (score 0):

You are not dealing correctly with the possibility that data is empty. Here is how you can solve this:

```
import ruamel.yaml
import sys


def read_file(f):
    with open(f, 'r') as yaml:
        return ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml)

new_dict = {}

new_dict['first_name'] = sys.argv[1]
new_dict['last_name'] = sys.argv[2]
new_dict['role'] = sys.argv[3]

data = read_file('hiera.yaml')
try:
    pos = len(data)
    data.insert(pos, sys.argv[1], dict, None)


except TypeError:
    pass

ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(new_dict, open('hiera.yaml', 'a'),
                            block_seq_indent=1)
```

Notice the `try ... except` block.

Also note, I am opening the file in append mode. Otherwise, the content will be erased if already there.

Demo time:

```
 $ cat hiera.yaml 
 Jon:
 $ python test.py  Alice Doe Developer
 cat hiera.yaml 
 Jon:
 first_name: Alice
 role: Developer
 last_name: Doe
```

This worked with existing data.
Now, let's test with an empty file:

```
 $ rm hiera.yaml 
 $ touch hiera.yaml
 $ python test.py  Alice Doe Developer
 $ cat hiera.yaml 
 first_name: Alice
 role: Developer
 last_name: Doe
```

Works too!

Comment: Thanks Oz123 & Anthon.

Comment: but, Anthon's answer is more appropriate for me.

Comment: Oz123 I am a bit worried about your use of opening for appending. IMO should never do that with a YAML file and you could make the file unloadable (i.e. incorrect YAML) if you do so.